# Storing unknown amount of user input-based variables

Tags: c#

I need to write a program in C# where the user will input serveral numbers, the amount of numbers is decided by the user. How can I store these inputs as int/doubles? Should I be using the array method for this, or something completely different?

To be exact, I'm writing a program that's going to calculate the total resistance of a parallel resistor network.

Sorry for asking such a basic question. Could not find examples for C# online.

Comment: [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) or [lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) are the way to go.

Comment: Post your code ([mcve])

Answer (score 1):

I think you can box the value inside and object class and unbox it as needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using static System.String;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input;
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            List<object> numbers = new List<object>();
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            while (!IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                if (input.Contains('.'))
                    numbers.Add(double.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, culture));
                else
                    numbers.Add(int.Parse(input));

                Console.Write("Input: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            foreach (object number in numbers)
            {
                if (number is double)
                {
                    double value = (double)number;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Double value: {value.ToString()}");
                }
                else
                {
                    int value = (int)number;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Integer value: {value.ToString()}");
                }

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please read about Collections in .net and choose your own
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

Answer (score 0):

```
U can use a List and create a object for this.
Example 
//object
public class Data{
 public int value1 {get;set;}
 public double value2 {get;set;}
}

and use on list
var values = new List<Data>();

var data = new Data();
data.value1 = 10;
data.value2 = 10.0;

values.add(data);

data.value1 = 20;
data.value2 = 20.0

values.add(data);


var sumInt = values.Sum(x => x.value1);
var sumDouble = values.Sum(x => x.value2);

!maybe this help.
```